# How can I define a property of an object that defines another complex property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

how would you solve the following type. There is a product, that has dynamic properties, but those will be defined upon product creation. Every product can have different variants and definitions.

```
type Product = {
  ...
  variantDefinitions: {
    code: string // eg color
    label: { en: string, cs: string } // how is color translated i18n
    possibleValues: { [key: string] : { en: string, cs: string } } // actual list of colors and its translations
  }[]

  variants: {
    id: string
    price: number
    [dynamically add its variantDefinitions codes]: one of predefined values (optional)
  }[]
}
```

Example of an object definition

```
variantDefinitions: [{
  code: 'color',
  label: { en: 'color', cs: 'barva' }
  possibleValues: { 
    red: { en: 'red', cs: 'cervena' }, 
    blue: { en: 'blue', cs: 'modra' },  
  }
}]

variants: [{
  id: '1'
  price: 1
  color: 'blue' // <-- force 'color' here and its available values like 'blue'
}]
```

I guess I have to use generics but this is not a trivial example for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not my finest work but it's a bit fiddly if you *have* to work with this structure:

```js
type VariantDefinitions = [{
  code: 'color',
  label: { en: 'color', cs: 'barva' },
  possibleValues: { 
    red: { en: 'red', cs: 'cervena' }, 
    blue: { en: 'blue', cs: 'modra' },  
  }
}]

type VariantCode = VariantDefinitions[number]["code"];
type PossibleValuesFor<Code extends VariantCode> = {
    [key in keyof VariantDefinitions as VariantDefinitions[key] extends { code: Code } ? key : never]:
        VariantDefinitions[key] extends { possibleValues: { [value: string]: any } }
            ?   (keyof VariantDefinitions[key]["possibleValues"])
            :   never
}
type PossibleValueFor<Code extends VariantCode> = PossibleValuesFor<Code>[keyof PossibleValuesFor<Code>]

type Variant = {
    id: string;
    price: number;
} & Partial<{
    [code in VariantCode]: PossibleValueFor<code>
}>

const variants: Variant[] = [{
  id: '1',
  price: 1,
  color: 'blue'
}]
```

[Full playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwHbACIQGZNU4JAe1QGcoBeKAbQCgBvWqKAYyIBMIAuKAcjYA2RBLwA0TKALgAjCAJ70oEVD35EhI0a1KrpiAG5xeUAL7jmYIqVJJpAiPAEBXCDqiKJzBBHYKlKvm92MW1VFggEfWUjUy1PKDsXP2VdZwgQljdeAFsOBBizZgkTWjMGCTZOVRsAL3TzSRk5ZIDeWvrQviiBJABrK2BjMosrGzsHODS3D2ZmUmzJ+Xd-aoWBAQystYK42caEAHNuZZS+KUOOzNVu3p2i5hKSgF1aWlBIWEQUdABhDmgqPBkGhMDg8ARiGRqKgnNlZAgntQAESVCBIp4Abje4GgAAVRrZ7I4XKQAGLCAA8f04SgAHsBlOxyEDvsBqRAAHyUdzxai9CAgKB4KD8kBEbCfYHoLC4fCEEjkODMr4gmXg+VQ0VPOkM1BM5aonjs0xQAD8IoFUB4qAgUQRXHiexZqrBcshpD5Au1EHpjPIiks1kJEymfmohjSPFIwGQqAOTx4aEFJlMjr2s3NzAAFKLxZLWWq3QrPSBEUjA2MiZMSeiAJRp9NW2Y2u2lbEffFB8bEiDkhBU-46v35kHsrlUTuVkMkvsDzgckt5yfBntkyljl7t6DO9Dcxh7JC+KDR2MHLF7MDIcLW2HwrEpgBkUFxiEIkwp+9m1FRQtQI9+-wJs+BLdtWvaUqiHKlFBtBsGQwBQIYUrAG4O7ANQ2pUNQn6HqoACMYgSJeSDXlAeENIIwipC4IQAPS0VAFIALRMVA2DCOEfCUSIUAABYRNAaDsEKKFQHAhhIFI4yIWB5A9PyfCJOkEjtKo5xHLwpRPEAA)

Hopefully gives you some ideas.